# username in cookie

Tags: php, security, cookies

I want to create a cookie with ONLY a user's username. I want our login form to remember a username (if the user chooses), but they will have to enter their password every time.

Is there any risk in just having the username in the cookie? Should there be any sort of encryption on the username?

Suggestions?

Comment: you can do if users are using from public computer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although, this is not the best thing to do, the answer to your question is
You can encrypt and store the username in the cookie, read and decrypt at runtime

ENCRYPT:

```
base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($username), $salt, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($username))));
```

DECRYPT

```
rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($username), base64_decode($salt), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($username))), "\0");
```

Comment: Why might an error be thrown when using mcrypt functions? I am on PHP version 5.2.6

- **Fatal error**: Call to undefined function mcrypt_encrypt()

Answer (score 2):

As long as that cookie never grants the user privileges, that's fine from a security standpoint. Cookies can easily be spoofed, so you don't want manually-created cookies to allow someone into secure parts of the site.

It does expose some sniffable data to anyone who happens to look at the cookie jar, which may or may not matter to you and/or your users.

Comment: The only purpose of the cookie is to populate the username input box at login. It will not be used to authenticate in any way, shape, or form.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen systems, such as [Moodle](http://moodle.org) do that. So it is not uncommon. There *are* risks in doing this, but options on sites like this have become common.